# Две строки пропущен(о/ы)

Tags: согласование, причастия, окончания

Здесь вопросов нет:

> Одна строка пропущена

А здесь сомневаюсь, как правильно:

> Две строки пропущены
>   Две строки пропущено

Здесь ведь так верно?

> Пять строк пропущено

Пожалуйста, кроме конкретного ответа, расскажите: как называется эта конструкция и какое правило здесь применяется?

Comment: К сожалению, я не могу это аргументировать ничем, но обычно вроде в тексте (с вариантами) косой ставят...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, тут - умышленно или нет, - но спрашивающий скрыл существенную деталь.

Если пропущен фрагмент длинной две строки, то рекомендательно (не императивно) - именно "пропущено две строки".

Если же это две строки в разных частях текста, то, простите, у меня ну никак язвк не повернется сказать иное чем "пропущен**ы** две строки".

Comment: Имеется в виду один фрагмент длиной в две строки.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.
СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ

XLIII. СОГЛАСОВАНИЕ СКАЗУЕМОГО С ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ

§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)

Comment: Вы меня извините, но я из вашего ответа не понял, каков всё-таки ответ.

Comment: Прочитав параграф, должны были понять. Сомневаюсь, что я могу сказать лучше Розенталя. Однозначного ответа нет, зависит от контекста.

Comment: Вам дали  ссылку, почитайте внимательно: если подчеркивается активность и раздельность действия каждого действующего лица, например: Ряд сотрудников отдела заявили, что они не согласны с позицией администрации; но: Ряд вопросов, стоявших на повестке дня, за недостатком времени не обсуждался (подлежащее обозначает неодушевленный предмет). Поэтому сказуемое в страдательном обороте обычно ставится в единственном числе, так как подлежащее обозначает объект действия, а не его субъект, например: Большинство участников соревнований размещено в пансионатах; Ряд молодых бизнесменов направлен за рубеж;

Comment: У Вас страдательный оборот, объект действия, сущ. неодуш., предпочтительно ед. число- "пропущено", но возможно и множ. число,ошибки не будет.

Comment: Niemand, в чем могу с автором согласиться, так это в том, что здесь не принято давать ответ путем простой ссылке. Нужен именно ответ. А в остальном - совет: не связывайтесь Вы с ним. Ничего не докажете, я уже убедился не один раз.

Comment: @Людмила ссылка — это не ответ. Ссылки устаревают и вообще что угодно может с ними происходить. Поэтому в ответе должен быть собственно ответ, а ссылка может его только дополнять.

Comment: Ну, со ссылкой или без, вы все же разобрались?

Comment: @Niemand: спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта, в зависимости от того, какое значение говорящий придаёт "строкам".

1. *Вне контекста* из выбранного варианта может следовать авторское отношение к "строкам" (акцент на их *количестве*, либо на *содержании*). Если сказать "пропущен**о** две строки", то это воспринимается как количественная оценка уровня технических ошибок в тексте, например, копированном. В альтернативном же варианте ("пропущен**ы** две строки") просматривается важность пропущенных строк по содержанию. Это в предположении сознательного, разборчивого выбора выражений автором.
2. Могут быть и *контекстные ограничения*, делающие один из вариантов явно предпочтительным.

2a) Если речь идёт о "пропавшей" паре конкретных строк, например, при переписывании фрагмента пушкинского стиха, то уместным выглядит только вариант "пропущен**ы** две строки": эти строки знает наизусть говорящий и скорее всего, их должен был знать ошибшийся исполнитель. Акцент - на содержании строк. Не исключено, что эти строки  будут затем процитированы.

2б) И наоборот, если речь идёт (условно) о программе, подсчитывающей выпадения строк из-за технических сбоев, выпавшие строки обезличены и смысл утверждения - в донесении информации об их количестве (было "пропущен**о** две строки").

Answer (score 0):

Согласно ссылке Niemand-а, "форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов", что в данном случае, как мне кажется, и имеет место, поэтому правильно, на мой взгляд, в единственном числе: *две строки пропущен**о**.*

Comment: По ссылке - недвусмысленно сказано, что оба варианта  возможны. А догадки о "совокупности" - трудно признавать достоверными даже при наличии контекста.

Comment: Для меня было очевидно, что имеется в виду фрагмент, поэтому я так и ответил.